# A WebView method was called on thread 'FinalizerDaemon' BUT MY APP HAS NO WEBVIEW

Tags: android, android-webview, android-strictmode

I'm using StrictMode policy while developing my app:

```
  StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                    .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .penaltyDeath()
                    .build());
```

I'm experiencing a new type of crash, which appeared from seems nowhere:

```
W/WebView: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'FinalizerDaemon'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 2) {7424b6e} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 2) {7424b6e})
    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2695)
    at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:969)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.e(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.destroy(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.t.destroy(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:10)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.interstitial.b.finalize(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:2)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


2019-06-17 15:25:59.035 31170-31180/hu.myapp.name D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.WebViewMethodCalledOnWrongThreadViolation
        at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2695)
        at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:969)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.e(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.destroy(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.t.destroy(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.interstitial.b.finalize(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290004@20290004.249178941.249178941:2)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My app DOES NOT HAVE ANY web views, that is why this is strange.

This is really annoying, the crash doesn't include any lines of my code, only android and google packages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently you're using an in-app ads SDK that uses a WebView (Admob?) See `com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview...`

Comment: Your app may not, but the admob SDK is. Have you tried using a different version, in case this is a bug in the SDK?

Comment: From my experience with WebView and StrictMode, probably it is not a bug. I our app we had to disable some checks (or reduce the penalty to log) in order to work around the problem.

Comment: Moving to an answer as it seems the more plausible explanation of the behavior you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're using an in-app ads SDK that uses a WebView (Admob?) See `com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview...`.

Plus, from my experience with `WebView` and `StrictMode`, the fact you're getting this behavior probably it is not a bug of the Ads SDK: I our app we had to disable some checks (or reduce the penalty to log) in order to work around the problem (we do use `WebView`, and the `WebView` itself creates issues with `StrictMode` because of disk access done from UI thread and similar issues).

Comment: The real problem/annoying part that I really have AdMob integration but in debug mode I don't show any ads. There are NONE webViews visible in my app while using strict mode. I would say this is a bug.

Comment: Then, yes, it looks like the WebView is being created regardless you're showing it or not, so this most likely is a bug on the AdMob SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with admob.

Here what I do to reproduce the crash:

- when my activity is opened, I load an interstitial -> interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
- But some design reason depending of user action, I do not need this interstitial because i will never show it.
- The user action open another activity and destroy the one which contains the interstitial

-> If the user open this new activity when the instertial was fully loaded, I don't have any problem.

-> If the user open this new activity before the intertial was fully loaded, then the crash happens. Surely because when the interstitial finnish to download its data, it intialisze an webview. But since, the instertitial variable has already reached the garbage collector...

So the solution, would be to have to way to cancel the interstial request, but i found nothing to do that...

Not really sure how to solve my issue. I don't wanna wait the end of loading to respond to the user action. Neither i can't delay or ignore the loading of interstitial presuming what will be the user action...

Sorry to reactivate this post, but seem to me the same problem. I don't give the solution but at least the exact way to reproduce the crash. if someone from admob come here, please add a method to cancel a processing loading

Comment: so my solution to keep my design and get the behavior i want was to implement the interstitial as singleton and add a destroy method. If when the interstitial has finish to load, I destroy my singleton. Not the perfect solution, because i continu to load in background some I know I will never use... Quite crazy they didn't think to add a cancel request method...